# Remove currency symbol on prices from some pages - NOT ALL

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, currency-symbol

I would like to remove the currency symbols from prices, but not in the cart and checkout page. It could be done with CSS but is there another way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

> **Step-1 : Create routes.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/etc/frontend and add below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="customlayout" id="customlayout">
            <module name="VendoreName_CustomLayout"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> **Step-2 : Create module.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/etc and add below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendoreName_CustomLayout" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> **Step-3 : Create Index.php file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/Controller/Index and add below code.**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomLayout\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

> **Step-4 : Create customlayout_index_index.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/layout and add below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="VendoreName_CustomLayout::css/my_custom_layout_css.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

**Here the file name must be like routename_controllername_actionname.xml and all characters must be in lowercase.**

***Add hide currency symbols css into your main css and add hide currency symbols into this css file to app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/web/css/my_custom_layout_css.css***

> **Step-5 : Create events.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/etc and add below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="custom_layout_css_js_add" instance="VendoreName\CustomLayout\Observer\CustomLayoutHandler" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> **Step-6 : Create CustomLayoutHandler.php file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/Observer and add below code.**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomLayout\Observer;

class CustomLayoutHandler implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $pageResult,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->_pageResult = $pageResult;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getData('layout');
        $pageName = $this->request->getFullActionName();
        $pageList = [];
        $pageList[] = 'checkout_cart_index';
        //$pageList[] = 'add page name ';
        if (in_array($pageName, $pageList)) {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customlayout_index_index');
        }

    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

**Add this css,**

```
     span.price::first-letter {
        display: none;
     }
    .checkout-cart-index.page span.price::first-letter, .checkout-index-index span.price::first-letter {
        display:inline-block !important;
     }
```